# Using Get-Job to test-connection, but quite different

Tags: powershell, connection

It's my first post here, I'm tring to write scripts on PS on my own, now my target is to write script that checks if computer is online at network, for example: test-Connection 192.168.0.1, 2, 3 etc. Doing this one by one on loop for takes some time if some computers are offline, I've found some tutorials on this site to use -AsJob param, but I'm not really Sure how could it work. I mean I'd like to output every checked PC to excel, so i need if operator. eg:

if (Job1 completed successfull (computer pings)){
do smth}...

I need to get output from Job boolean (true/false), but one by one. I'm taking my first steps in PS, I've made program that checks it one by one in for loop, but as i said it take some time till my excel file fill...

I can see, that AsJob makes working more effective and I think it's important to understand it

Thanks and sorry for bad text formatting, by the time I'll go on with this!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If using Test-Connection on multiple computers with -Quiet how do I know which result is for which computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65998379/if-using-test-connection-on-multiple-computers-with-quiet-how-do-i-know-which-r). Note that `ForEach-Object -Parallel` creates jobs automatically behind the scenes.

Comment: That's not really my problem, I'm trying to check multiple computers at one time, if I'd do it one by one, It'd take long while. I have problem with:

How to output Recieve-Jobs like:

$ip = (some IPs)
$ip | Select-Object -Frist 3 | ForEach-Object{
Start-Job -Name $_ -ScriptBlock {
$temp = Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -Quiet
if($temp){
Write-Host "$_ is online"
}
else{
write-host "$_ is offline"
}
}
}

I want to: When I Use Receive-Job output is:
ip1 is online
ip2 is offline
ip3 is online
(...)
I want to check Ip's from 192.169.50.1 - 255

Comment: With `ForEach-Object -Parallel` you actually check multiple computers at the same time. It is like creating jobs, but much simpler to handle. By default, it creates 5 jobs at maximum. You can increase that like `ForEach-Object -Parallel -ThrottleLimit 10`. Now it would run 10 jobs at maximum.

Comment: Just a note that `ForEach-Object -Parallel` is not available until Powershell v7.

Comment: I've replied an error: ForEach-Object : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.I think It's no longer avalible "param -Parallel"
Anybody has any tips? 
I'd Like just to get output if job was completed successfull or not, than I could use if statment to simply fill excel cells with IP and status

Comment: https://wtools.io/paste-code/b3MP
I'm trying to run this, but It won't output anything...

Answer (score 1):

In your example, in the Start-Job scriptblock you are trying to access `$_` which is not available in the codeblock scope.  If you replace `$_` with `$args[0]` it should work since you are passing in the $ip value as an argument

Your Example

```
$ipki = Get-Content 'C:\Users\pchor\Desktop\ipki.txt'
foreach ($ip in $ipki) {
    Start-Job -Name "$ip" -ScriptBlock {
        Test-Connection $_ -Count 1  # <---- replace $_ with $args[0]
    } -ArgumentList $_  # <----- change $_ to $ip 
}
```

You'll probably also want to wait for all the jobs to finish.  I recommend something like this

```
$computers = @(
    'www.google.com'
    'www.yahoo.com'
)

$jobs = $computers |
    ForEach-Object {
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Computer = $using:_
                Alive    = Test-Connection $using:_ -Count 1 -Quiet
            }
        }
    }

# Loop until all jobs have stopped running
While ($jobs |
        Where-Object { $_.state -eq 'Running' }) {
    "# of jobs still running $( ($jobs | Where-Object {$_.state -eq 'Running'}).Count )";
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
}
$results = $jobs | Receive-Job | Select-Object Computer, Alive
$results | Format-Table
```

Output

```
Computer       Alive
--------       -----
www.google.com  True
www.yahoo.com   True
```

To modify the properties to what you want there are different ways of doing this.  Easiest in this case is probably to use a calculated property

```
$newResults = $results | 
    Select-Object Computer, 
    @{Label = 'State'; Expression = { if ($_.Alive) { 'Online' } else { 'Offline' } } }
```

Objects will now look like this (I added another fake address to illustrate offline state)

```
Computer                 State
--------                 -----
www.google.com           Online
www.yahoo.com            Online
xxx.NotAValidAddress.xxx Offline
```

You can then export the objects to csv using `Export-csv`

```
$newResults | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\output.csv
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted, how could I access "true" value of every single adress? 
for example:
If (www.google.com -eq True){
write-host= "Online"
}
else{
Write-host = "offline"
}

Comment: Updated answer to include how to transform the object with calculated property and how to export the data to csv file

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, now It's time to analyse your code to understand it! B)